# Power on reset and watchdog signal combination question

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, reset, nxp

I'm working with the i.MX RT1050 processors and designing a POR circuit.

I found the following circuit in the [reference design](https://www.nxp.com/products/processors-and-microcontrollers/applications-processors/i.mx-applications-processors/i.mx-rt-series/i.mx-rt1050-evaluation-kit:MIMXRT1050-EVK) but I don't understand how it's meant to work.

[image]

The UM805RE is a voltage supervisor that generates a reset when VCC goes low. It also has a Manual Reset (MR) that triggers when it is brought low.

What I don't understand is how the POR_BUTTON and WDOG_B signals are combined. I simulated it, and the POR_BUTTON signal gets through to trigger the MR.

But the WDOG_B signal is blocked by a capacitor, and won't trigger

Can anyone help explain this, is it a mistake in the reference design?

Thanks

Comment: It seems to work. Sure you got that r45 1Meg right? BTW, There is a 20k vcc pullup inside the UM805 MR pin.

Comment: Not sure, I didn't actually design this one it's from the reference design.

I don't understand how any signal on WDOG_B can get past the C60 1uF capacitor?

Comment: I think a low voltage on the wdog side would still produce a low at the MR side. I can add a LTSpice simulation if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of the waveform with the iMX and reset circuit. The output stage of the WD is not entirely accurate, it will probably behave differently when the MCU actually resets. But it seems to work. 
[image: circuit]
[image: waveform]